# XMLHttpRequest: Browser support for sendAsBinary?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is Firefox the only that supports the sendAsBinary method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, I believe only FF3+ supports this, though there is a [workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35705) for **Chrome**.

Comment: I believe the workaround is to define you own sendAsBinary via prototype as such:try {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary) return;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
      function byteValue(x) {
        return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
      }
      var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
      var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
      this.send(ui8a.buffer);
    }
  } catch (e) {}

Comment: I like how `Marko` answered Mr. `Polo`.

Answer (score 2):

The links around http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35705 are very confusing, but I do not think there is any workaround on Chrome 8 for POST'ing binary data.

You can convert the data to base64 and upload that, but then the server has to be able to decode it.

Chrome 9 (currently in Dev channel, not even Beta yet) lets you do XmlHttpRequest.send(blob) where the blob's bytes are sent as-is (not converted to utf-8), so the non-standard XmlHttpRequest.sendAsBinary() is not necessary for binary file uploads.

You must create this blob from the "binary" string that is in evt.target.result after a successful FileReader.readAsBinaryString(). That requires using ArrayBuffer and Uint8Array, which are not available in Chrome 8.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, yes, only Firefox supports it. It's not part of the [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), so there's no guarantee that it'll ever be supported by any other browser.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, but I'm also using Prototype.js. Seems it has some replacement for map function and it were throwing TypeError for me `Object ..file data here.. has no method 'each'`
So i used this replacement instead

```
//fix sendAsBinary for chrome
try {
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary == 'undefined') {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(text){
      var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
      var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
      this.send(ui8a);
    }
  }
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for Chrome is explained at the following URL:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35705