# low level information needed for the uploading of the files via http and html

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, http

I have been studying the process of the file uploading via http. My question is that how the file is upload via ajax and not through full page postbacks. I want to know how the file is transmitted via ajax. I read  [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) article. The article mentioned says this method is not possible if the FormData is not available. But I want to know is there anyother method to make the ajax file upload work on all the browser without using iframe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without `FormData` you need to use `iframe`. Alternativly there are libraries which emulate the functionality using  a hidden flash or silverlight.

Comment: This has been very frustrating. I don't know much about the flash or silverlight. How much work will be required for a flash beginner to understand and creator file uploader in flash or silverlight? and which one will be better? Seems like another set of question but will like to know if you can help?

Comment: @user1698985 i don't use any of there. but i would use an already existing e.g. [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Comment: I want to understand the procedure not interested in third party controls. Thanks for the ultimate answer. I was frustrated searching the solution.